# JsonNode内MapのNull→空文字変換

Tags: java, json, jackson

お世話になっております。
Javaでサーバサイドの開発をしているものです。

JacksonのJsonNodeの仕組みを使ってデータバインディングしているのですが、JsonNode内のMapのValueにNullがあった場合に空文字列に変換したい場合、どのような処理をすれば良いのでしょうか？
Mapの中にKey/Valueを追加したり、Mapの中のKey/Valueを削除したりするサンプルは見つかるのですが、上記のような具体的な処理内容が見つからず、困っております。

Comment: 実装したコードも載せて、もう少し具体的に何がうまくいかないか教えていただけないでしょうか。nullを空文字に変換したいなら、`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.defaultString()`を使えばいいと思いますが。

Comment: 反応ありがとうございます！
ObjectMapperというJsonNodeに対して変換ルールを設定して、変換するようなクラスがあり、それを使用して出来ないかと考えましたが、ちょうど良い変換ルールが見つからずに困っています。

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false); //こんな感じでNull→空文字を設定したい。
JsonNode node = mapper.convertValue(hogehogeEntity, JsonNode.class);//あるBeanをJsonNodeに入れたい。

Comment: [こういうこと](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782284/how-to-serialize-in-jackson-json-null-string-to-empty-string)ですかね？

Comment: やりたいことはそういうことです。ただ、このサンプルコードはコンパイルエラーが出てしまい、、、実装が間違っているのでしょうか。。
- 型 ObjectMapper のメソッド setSerializerProvider(DefaultSerializerProvider) は引
  数 (StdSerializerProvider) に適用できません

Comment: StdSerializerProvider serializedProvider = new StdSerializerProvider();
        serializedProvider.setNullValueSerializer(new NullSerializer());

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setSerializerProvider(serializedProvider);

Comment: 使用しているJacksonのバージョンは何ですか？

Comment: Jackson 2.7を使用しています。

Comment: 頂いたサンプルコードについてですが、NullSerializer.serializeメソッドがvoidで、setNullValueSerializerの引数について、JsonSerializer<Object>である必要があるというエラーが出てしまいますね。。

Comment: 間違いがありました。回答を修正しました

Answer (score 1):

コメントの内容から判断して、以下のような実装でうまくいくのではないかと思います。

```
// First: need a custom serializer provider
DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl sp = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();
sp.setNullValueSerializer(new NullValueSerializer());
// And then configure mapper to use it
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
m.setSerializerProvider(sp);
```